# Hide the path of media files from developer tools or inspect element

Tags: php, security

How can i hide the file path which is showing in inspect element or developer tools of any browser.? Is there any way to restrict user to know the file path on browser.

Comment: No. If it's in your HTML code, you can't hide it.

Comment: You cant, it depicts the sole purpose of the web which is meant to be free and Open when it comes to coding pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to hide network traffic from a browsers developer console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487643/is-it-possible-to-hide-network-traffic-from-a-browsers-developer-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The browser needs the path to display your media file. Since all communication between your server and the browser happens over plain text formats and there's no secret backchannel or something, the path will have to be visible to anyone who looks.

Comment: so there is no solution to hide a the file path from user ?

Comment: can i encrypt the file path ??

Comment: **THE BROWSER NEEDS THE ACTUAL PATH TO DISPLAY THE FILE.** If you're hiding the path from anyone, you're also hiding it from the browser. If you're allowing anyone to see the file, then anyone can also see the path. What are you trying to do here? Why are you trying to do it?!

Comment: i am trying to do it because i want to give 30 sec preview or sample of audio songs to my user before downloading

Comment: Then you will need to create a separate 30 sec sample file (the URL of which anyone will be able to see) and protect the actual file with some form of authentication.

Comment: okey thankyou for your help. but i have 90,000 audio files. and it take a long time to create separate 30 sec sample of 90,000 files

Comment: But that's what you'll have to do. You can automate it, you don't have to do that by hand. It could even be done on-the-fly by PHP.