# Is it possible to hide network traffic from a browsers developer console?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, networking

I want to hide a download link from a common user that knows how to use a developer console and look at their network tab. I know they would have other means to detect the traffic but as long as they cannot see evidence of a web request within the dev console I'm satisfied. Is this possible or will every request made within a web page show up? I'm agnostic to any tool that can provide this service.

Comment: You can use a websocket to "hide" whats going on. But if you really dont want the user to make something strange with the download information, you should generate some one time links, which Will expire once they have been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no way to do this that would be reliable. You can obfuscate all you like, but the DevTools can see everything, and if they couldn't it would be a bug that the browser developers will go fix.

(The idea of using a WebSocket is a fun one, but even websocket frames are visible in DevTools these days).

Stepping back a bit, you should elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do and why you think preventing the use of Developer Tools would be useful. There is likely to be another solution that works better for what you want to achieve.